# Why Pod must have its first letter capitalized in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I saw in k8s operators repo that `a Pod` is always spelled with P capitalized.
For example, a comment like `This function creates a Pod`, instead of `This function creates a pod`. Note the capitalization in Pod.

Why do people enforce the spelling of Pod as Pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this may not be the best answer but still, here are my two pennies worth on the matter.

I think capitalizing P(od), an S(ervice) or a D(eployment) gives clarity and avoids the confusion that it is being referred to in the context of a K8s resource. It adds clarity for words with multiple meanings, "service" (one might be referring to a microservice, who knows ¯_(ツ)_/¯) and "deployment" obviously have other meanings.

I have come across a few such discussions with one of them here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/20862

Also, some widely used documentation style guides patterns like:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/contribute/style/style-guide/

https://developers.google.com/style/capitalization

help set conventions & guidelines which help to ensure consistency, clarity & standardization across the sytem, especially within the technical community where people could be working on multiple teams/domains/projects etc.

I'm sure I or someone could elaborate this as much as one has time to spare but I hope it gives you some idea behind the thought process and more importantly it makes sense :)